# sorting in XPath using Java

Tags: java, javascript

I am using XML in my project for data to be Insert/Update/Delete & Searching. 
currently i am using XPath for doing the above operations from my JAVA application.

How can i sort the data[ascending/descending] while reading from XML file using XPath.

Can anyone tell me the best way to full-fill this requirement. It's an urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

1. XPath will give you a list of elements in the form of an array of Nodes.
2. Now this becomes a typical case of sorting an array (hence  you can use any of those many [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) ), but not so straightforward as the elements of the array will be Nodes and you need to compare two nodes.
3. U will have to write a function where in you will pass two array elements (Nodes). This fn will return true/false depending on comparison of two nodes.
4. In this function,  extract the values based on which the sorting is to be done. Compare those two values and return true/false.